# Why does Allah want animals killed by humans?

Tags: allah, animals

Allah created this universe.  He created human and animals.  But I don't understand why Allah wants animals killed by the hands of human.  Why bakrid is celebrated by killing goats?

Comment: Why did God let Lions and tigers eat deer?

Comment: What is bakrid? There's no specification for killing or slaughtering goats on any Islamic 'Id

Comment: @Medi1Saif Bakrid is Eid Ul Adha.

Answer (score 2):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him his family and companions

Allah Swt says in Quran 17:70

"**And We have certainly honored the children of Adam and carried them on the land and sea and provided for them of the good things and preferred them over much of what We have created, with [definite] preference**."

and in Quran 2:29

"**It is He Who hath created for you all things that are on earth**...."

which means that Allah swt has created different animals for our purposes and needs not only their meat or milk we use but we also get benefit from them in our clothing like sheeps,camel hairs some insects are also used .Human beings are given a free will but are created to worship Allah as in Quran 51:56

**"I created the jinn and humankind only that they might worship me…"**

now Animals are not given free will nor they are answerable to Allah swt as they follow nature prescribed by Allah Swt.If you would look around in nature there are lots of insects and plants which are eaten by these animals which we take as our meal so these plants would not be considered as innocent on behalf of this mechanism.These all are natural process and laws of Allah Subhan o Taala in this world which no one denies.Now it does not prove that using these resources as our needs would be against the nature or laws.Keeping in mind that there is a big difference in "killing" and "sacrificing", Why Muslims sacrifice an animal on some special day when islam condemns to kill any innocent soul

**Hadrat Zaid ibn Arqam reported that the companions of the Messenger of Allah asked: “O Messenger of Allah! What is this sacrifice?” He said, “It is the practice of your father Abraham.” They asked, “What is the reward for us in it?” He said, “For every hair, you will be rewarded.” They asked, “for the wool, O Messenger of Allah?” He said, “For every strand of wool you will be rewarded.” [Sunan Ibn Majah, Vol. 1, Page 226]**

these sort of sacrifices are also mentioned in previous scriptures at different times.On this day of Eid ul Adha ,the meat of an animal after slaughterd with name of Allah swt following His commands then is distributed among poor needy and others,A True Muslim wants to please Allah swt submits his will according to Allah swt not to please his own nafs,

In Quran 22:37

**"It is not their meat nor their blood that reaches Allah; it is your piety that reaches Him**".

Allah swt and his Messenger knows best.

Comment: Nice explanation especially the last ayyah wins the debate!!

Answer (score 0):

What some people are saying about Bakra Eid is just ridiculous. Animals are created for us to get benefit from them like food, milk, trade, transport etc. I do not think there is anything bad about sacrificing them. If you think it is cruelty then I would say that it is performed for sake of humanity and to help poor who can't afford meat the whole year but eat once in Eid and an animal can be sacrificed for a human!!!

***Is any human more gentle to animals than its creator? No, never. If not then how can any one say that Creator is ordering us to be cruel to them?***

Comment: **<comments deleted>**. Comments should primarily be used to ask for more information and suggest improvements. Not discussions. Take it [chat] if you want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You're an animal! Why would God want you to kill us?

It's your emotional drive that counts; your purpose, your reason, your "why?".  We have 3 essential motivations in the human "state":

1. Survival instinct

   The one that lets you tap your fullest potential when danger or a potential threat is around, like running when crossing the street, fast shifted focus when hearing an unexpected loud sound, or when you're so tired and about to go unconscious and suddenly you obey that instinct when the fire alarm fires up and you're suddenly your favourite super hero or villain!

Also why do people eat each other while at sea?  In this case, the survival instinct gets mentally distorted by one's nature.

2. Interior motivation

   The most powerful ones because of their high level of consciousness and mindfulness and sustainability.
3. Exterior motivation

   That nice kind, fun-loving, playful, joyful smiling, happy, respectful stranger you meet.

Which are the ones that you might have forgotten while facing your bump.

Peace, love and much respect!  Keep digging through questions!